# asp.net session state Failed to login to session state SQL server for user

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to setip session state in my asp.net projject.

here is how I am doing it:

```
C:\Users\Asif>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -S
 ASIF-VAIO\MSSQLSERVER12 -E -ssadd -sstype t

Start adding session state.

....

Finished.
```

asp.net state service is running on my system.

here is what i put in web.config

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=ASIF-VAIO\MSSQLSERVER12;database=CapitalStackersDB;User=webcider;Password=mypassword;" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"  timeout="100" />
```

I added entry in host file and when i run that url, I get:

```
Failed to login to session state SQL server for user 'webcider'.
```

Comment: Did you get the solution of this question ?

Comment: For those who come along later the following may be of assistance: http://forums.asp.net/t/1510479.aspx?Login+failed+for+user+IIS+APPPOOL+DefaultAppPool

Answer (score 0):

Open the IIS there you find the application pool right click the mouse go to advance setting and change the Identity under process model.